# Clarification about Stochastic distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What does this mean - "the x distribution is stochastically smaller than the y distribution"?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering).

Comment: Does the reply below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This means that $X$ and $Y$ are real valued random variables such that $\mathbb P(X\leqslant x)\geqslant\mathbb P(Y\leqslant x)$ for every real number $x$.

A characterization of the property that $X$ is stochastically smaller than $Y$ is that there exists some random variables $X'$ and $Y'$ defined on a common probability space such that:

- $X'$ is distributed like $X$,
- $Y'$ is distributed like $Y$,
- $X'\leqslant Y'$ with full probability.